# Add quotations to a key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this code:

```
var testObjs = ['This is One Test', 'A Sapphire Road', 'Ragon Done 12'];
var sampleAnswer = ['Hello', 'World', '123'];

var complexObj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < testObjs.length; i++) {
  complexObj[testObjs[i]] = sampleAnswer[i];
}

console.log(complexObj);
```

This creates an object with a value. Both are dynamically created and thus, we have this object:

```
{
    A Sapphire Road: "World"
    Ragon Done 12: "123"
    This is One Test: "Hello"
}
```

As you can see, the problem is that there is no double quotations. I want it to be like this (so it is valid):

```
{
    "A Sapphire Road": "World"
    "Ragon Done 12": "123"
    "This is One Test": "Hello"
}
```

How would I go about doing it?

Comment: Why do you think it is invalid?

Comment: The quotes in your last display example are not part of the string data. You seem to be conflating syntax used to define data with the data itself. What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? Do you need this for display purposes? Do you need quotes to actually be part of the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last line:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(complexObj));
```

Results with:

```
{"This is One Test":"Hello","A Sapphire Road":"World","Ragon Done 12":"123"}
```

But don’t bother with `console.log` result. This is presented without quotation marks only to you in console, for your convienience. In reality this is more like object in computer memory.

But if you need it to pass it in form you requested, stringify it with JSON.

Comment: Argh. Sometimes when you work so much, you forget the basics. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* correct. It's just showing without the quotes in the console. See the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/giriqatula/edit?js,console,output). No errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Josh said, nothing's wrong with your current code. However, if you still want to see quotation marks with it, try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < testObjs.length; i++) {
  complexObj["\"" + testObjs[i] + "\""] = sampleAnswer[i];
}
```